# Download Blob from Azure in Python using Client Credentials

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

What i am trying is fairly simple. However, I am receiving a Not Authorized error every time.

- I have an Azure container which contains some files
- I have an Azure AD account with client credentials
- trying to use the following python code to download a Blob and getting Not Authorized error. What am i doing wrong?

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

clientId="xxxxx"
clientSecret="xxxxx"
tenantId="xxxxx"
containerName="xxxxx"
account_url="https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net"

containerName="xxxxx"
blobName="xxxxx.txt"

token_credential=ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenantId, client_id=clientId,  client_secret=clientSecret)
blob_service_client=BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=token_credential)

blob_client=blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=containerName, blob=blobName)

downloader=blob_client.download_blob()
```

is there a get_token i need to call somewhere that i am missing?
the user has the following access in the Azure Storage account:

- Storage Blob Data Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Reader

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say the user, do you mean the service principal or the user running the code?

Comment: i meant the service principal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code.

You can try

token_credential.get_token("https://storage.azure.com/.default")

If it successfully gets a token, it is possible that your service principle doesn't have right permissions. Or you may use incorrect values for tenant_id/client_id/client_secret.

(I work in Azure SDK team in Microsoft)

Comment: weird thing....i ran the following code and then on it just worked even with out it

token_credential.get_token("https://storage.azure.com/.default")